Get "Make / Makefile" to run a glob AFTER another part of the program has run
I am trying use "make" to run pdfunite on a list of files that will not exist until after a program (cardito) has run, I do not know what the names of those files will be.
The problem I'm facing is that the
$(shell ls out/*.pdf)
Seems to be running BEFORE the Makefile command, and so is empty as the files don't exist until the for-loop runs. (see below)
I want the "shell ls" command to run after the files have been produced.
I have also tried a simple out/*.pdf and several other combinations of dollars brackets and braces.

cardfiles:
    cardito --trusted build -f customer.ito -c cards/customer.crd --fpath out/customers_f_ --bpath out/customers_b_
    cardito --trusted build -f staff.ito -c cards/staff.crd --fpath out/staff_f_ --bpath out/staff_b_
    cardito --trusted build -f extras.ito -c cards/extras.crd --fpath out/extras_f_ --bpath out/extras_b_

pdf: cardfiles
    - rm out/all_cards.pdf
    for f in out/*.svg ; do \
        inkscape --export-type=pdf $$f ; \
    done;
    pdfunite $(shell ls out/*.pdf)  out/all_cards.pdf

I'd like a glob that runs after part of the makefile has already run.

Wouldn’t just pdfunite out/*.pdf out/all_cards.pdf suffice?

(Also, don’t use ls like that.)

Ah yes, I think I went wrong by forgetting the "out/" in my ealrier attempts, it works now

In general if you find yourself tempted to use either $(shell ...) or $(eval ...) inside a recipe, you are probably going to be unhappy with the results.  Don't do that.  For $(shell...) remember that the recipe is already running in a shell, so there's rarely any point in using make's shell function as well: it will usually lead to confusion at best.
